# Is there a way to make an arrears report based on monthly payments?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to come up with a way to report monthly payments up until the account zeroes out.

The report as it is received:

[image]

The report as it should fill in:

[image]

Basically each month should report the full month arrear up until the total is reached and the last entry should be the amount remaining until the total is reached.

Answer (score 0):

If your data as shown starts in A2, use the following in E2:
`=LET(x,SUM($D2:D2),y,$B2,z,$C2,r,MOD(z,y),IF(x+y<=z,y,IF(x+r=z,r,"")))`